# Why do I keep getting NA values for my mean, median, and mode? (R) (10 days of Statistics)

Tags: r

I am trying to read the user input, and then compute the mean, median and mode.  However, I am unable to return any value other than NA.
[This is the exercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-basic-statistics/problem)

```
num_elements <- readline(prompt = "")
num_elements <- as.numeric(num_elements)

vec_elements <- readline(prompt = "")
vec_elements <- as.numeric(vec_elements)

mode <- function(x) {
ux <- unique(x)
ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

#find the mean
print(mean(vec_elements))

#find the median 
print(median(vec_elements))

#find the mode
print(mode(vec_elements))
```

Comment: Please mark the accepted answer to close the thread when you find the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are not specifying any numeric values.

Change the code as follows

```
num_elements <- scan("stdin", integer(), n = 1)
vec_elements <- scan("stdin", integer(), sep=" ", n = num_elements)
```

The thing is, if you don't use input method as `stdin`, it reads the next line of code and treats it as the input.

The second line specifies space as a separator. In case you want, you can specify it as a tabspace or a newline character as well.

You don't need `as.numeric()` in your code.